# Replacing multiple characters in NSString by multiple other characters using a dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, replace, nsstring

I would like to replace some characters in my string, by other characters, using a dictionary.

For instance, every "a" should be replaced by "1", and every "1" should be replaced by "9". What I don't want is every "a" to be replaced twice, ending up with a "9". Every character must be replaced just once.

I got this working using the following code, but I feel like it can be done more efficient.
Is this really the best I can do, or can you help me improve my code?

```
NSDictionary *replacements = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              // Object, Key,
                              @"1", @"a",
                              @"2", @"b",
                              @"3", @"c",
                              @"9", @"1",
                              @"8", @"2",
                              @"7", @"3",
                              nil];

NSString *string = @"abc-123";
NSMutableString *newString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:0];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < string.length; i++)
{
    NSString *c = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [string characterAtIndex:i]];
    id replacement = [replacements objectForKey:c];
    if (replacement != nil) {
        [newString appendString:replacement];
    } else {
        [newString appendString:c];
    }
}

NSLog(@"newString: %@", newString); // newString: 123-987 (Works!)
```

Just to be clear: This code is working for me, I just feel like it's very inefficient. I'm Looking for ways to improve it.

Thank you.

Comment: **You are iterating just one.**

And there can be many other logic but most of them would be using iteration and without iterating for each character, I don't think there could be any better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code is perhaps not much faster, but slightly simpler and shorter. 
It enumerates all characters of the string with a method that works correctly even with 
composed characters such as Emojis (which are stored as *two* characters in the string).

```
NSMutableString *newString = [string mutableCopy];

[newString enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [newString length])
                  options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
               usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
       NSString *repl = replacements[substring];
       if (repl != nil) {
           [newString replaceCharactersInRange:substringRange withString:repl];
       }
}];
```

Comment: I really like this. Thank you for your effort! If nothing better comes up, I'll accept this as the answer.

Comment: @MartinR what is replacements over here??

Comment: @Muju: `replacements` is the dictionary defined in the question.

Answer (score 0):

First Replace Every "1" by "9" and then Replace Every "a" by "1". Whats wrong with the logic ?

Your Dictionary is

```
@"1", @"a",
@"2", @"b",
@"3", @"c",
@"9", @"1",
@"8", @"2",
@"7", @"3",
nil
```

Replacing "1" by "9" will create

```
@"9", @"a",
@"2", @"b",
@"3", @"c",
@"9", @"9",
@"8", @"2",
@"7", @"3",
nil
```

and then Replacing "a" by "1" will create

```
@"9", @"1",
@"2", @"b",
@"3", @"c",
@"9", @"9",
@"8", @"2",
@"7", @"3",
nil
```

Do you want this as your Desired result ?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. The string I would like to manipulate is abc-123. Using the dictionary as shown above, the outcome will be 123-987. This is exactly what it should do. I would just like to know how I could improve my code, since I feel like it not very efficient the way it is now.

Comment: OK. Sorry i misunderstood your question.

Comment: No problem, I still appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

If ur rule is static like u said...i dont have sure if it is better

> ```
> NSString *string = @"abc-123";
> NSMutableString *newString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:0];
>
> for (NSInteger i = 0; i < string.length; i++)
> {
>
>     unichar cu = [string characterAtIndex:i];
>     if (cu >=97 && cu<=99){
>         cu -= 48;
>     }else if (cu>=49 && cu<=51){
>         cu = cu+10-((cu-48)*2);
>     }
>     [newString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",cu]];
> }
>
> NSLog(@"newString: %@", newString);
> ```

I'm using ASCII codes to match ur exactly rule.