# Changing letters of

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

In the following code, I check the NSString "newDNA" to see is it contains only ATCG. In the following if statement, if the foundRange.location==NSNotFound, I would like to change the letters in the string. If the letter is an A, I would like to change it to a T, G to C, C to G, and T to A. I'm not quite sure how to go about this.

```
//Check characters
    NSCharacterSet *ATCG = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"ATCG"];
    NSCharacterSet *invalidChars = [ATCG invertedSet];
    //NSString *target; // the string you wish to check
    NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, newDNA.length); // search the whole string
    NSRange foundRange = [newDNA rangeOfCharacterFromSet:invalidChars
                                                 options:0 // look in docs for other possible values
                                                   range:searchRange];
    if (foundRange.location==NSNotFound) {
        _testLabel.text = @"YESSSS";
    }else{
        _testLabel.text = @"NOOOOOO";
    }
```

Comment: There are many possible solutions, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313631/replacing-multiple-characters-in-nsstring-by-multiple-other-characters-using-a-d for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite simple:

```
    if (foundRange.location==NSNotFound) {
        _testLabel.text = [_testLabel.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"A" withString:@"T"]; 
        //And so on
    }
```

I just notice that you are going to change A to T and T to A, you may want to use a temporary value.

Something like, change A to temp, change T to A, change temp to T.